# How can i hide selectbox 2, if i select option in box 1?

Tags: jquery, show-hide, html-select

I need help! i want to hide the second select-box, by change select-box 1.

If i select `value 1` on select 1, select-box 2 is hide. If i select `value 2`, select-box 2 is show.

```
<tr class="variantCombobox">
<td class="label Flasche" valign="top">Flasche:</td>
<td>
<select id="variants[1]" name="variants[1]">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Esmeralda 100ml</option>
<option value="16">Esmeralda Geschenke-Set</option>
<option value="2">Picasso 200ml</option>
<option value="17">Picasso Geschenke-Set</option>
<option value="3">Carree 200ml</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="variantCombobox">
<td class="label Gläser" valign="top">Gläser:</td>
<td>
<select id="variants[3]" name="variants[3]">
<option selected="selected" value="18">Bitte wählen...</option>
<option value="19">Likörglas 1</option>
<option value="20">Likörglas 2</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>


var selectGlasses = 'tr.variantCombobox td.Flasche';
var selectedPresent = jQuery("[value='1']");
jQuery(selectGlasses).parent().next().hide();
jQuery('select').click(function(){
jQuery('option').find(function(){if ('select').contains(selectedPresent)});
jQuery(selectGlasses).parent().next().hide();
});
```

My 3 problems are, my english is very bad, i can't change classes or id's of select boxes and my script dosn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you'll have to escape the ids of your elements:

If it is:

```
id="variants[3]"
```

Then jQuery selector would be:

```
jQuery("#variants\\[3\\]")
```

Here is a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kj2rM/

```
$(function() {
var selectGlasses = 'tr.variantCombobox td.Flasche';
var selectedPresent = jQuery("[value='1']");
jQuery(selectGlasses).parent().next().hide();
jQuery('select:first').change(function() {
    var selectedVal=jQuery(this).val();
    if(selectedVal==1) {
        $('#variants\\[3\\]').closest("tr").hide();
    }
    else if(selectedVal==2) {
        $('#variants\\[3\\]').closest("tr").show();
    }
});                                     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedVal=$('#variants[1] option:selected').val();

if(selectedVal==1)
$('#variants[3]').hide();

else if(selectedVal==2)
$('#variants[3]').show();
```